# Angles between simple, closed geodesics on convex surface

Tags: riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, closed-geodesic

It is known that there are at least three simple, closed geodesics on
the surface of any smooth convex body $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the
Lusternik-Schnirelmann Theorem (see links below for references).
For $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ two such geodesics,
let $\alpha_\max( \gamma_1, \gamma_2 )$ be the largest angle among all
the crossings of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$.
My question is:

> ***Q***. Is there a lower bound on $\alpha_\max$, over all
> simple, closed geodesics on $K$,
> over all $K$?
> Or is it possible that, for some $K$,
> all crossing angles of all geodesic pairs can be arbitrarily small?

---

- [“The famous Lusternik-Schnirelmann Theorem of the Three Closed
  Geodesics”](https://mathoverflow.net/q/94174/6094)
- [Simple, closed geodesics in $\mathbb{S}^3$ manifold](https://mathoverflow.net/q/180482/6094).
- *Added*: [Angle between geodesics in hyperbolic surface](https://mathoverflow.net/a/182709/6094).

---

[image: ellipsoid]

<sup>Image from
the article [Geodesics on an ellipsoid](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid).</sup>

Comment: @dodd: One can ask my question for the torus or for other surfaces, but I am specifically interested in convex surfaces, where the L-S theorem guarantees a few simple, closed geodesics.

Comment: If you have only a few (finitely many) closed geodesics, there is a low bound of the angles.

Comment: @dodd: I'm afraid I don't understand your remark. What I'm seeking is a lower bound over all possible convex surfaces. I want to say: there must exist a pair of simple, closed geodesics that cross at angle $\ge \alpha$, where $\alpha$ holds over all convex surfaces.

Comment: That is not what you asked. In your question $K$ is fixed.

Comment: @dodd: Corrected; thank you!

Comment: Added Lee Mosher's reply to a [different question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/182673/6094), but with a conclusion that might hold for my question: angles "can be made as small as possible."

Comment: The other question has surface fixed and hyperbolic. It is a completely different situation. Of course the answer should be the same. It seems obvious if $K$ varies.  But I do not know how to prove it.